# optimizing query and table in mysql 5.1

Tags: mysql

I have a question regarding optimizing the following query/table

```
SELECT playitemid,MAX(playdatetime) 
        FROM   buma
        WHERE  licenseid = 1 AND playdatetime > Date_sub(Curdate(), INTERVAL 1 month) 
        GROUP  BY playitemid
```

For a table with 11 million records this can sometimes take over 30 seconds.

Here is the create statement for the table.

```
CREATE TABLE `buma` (
 `bumaid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`playitemid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`playdatetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`stopdatetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL, `licenseid` int(11) NOT NULL, editionid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`bumaid`),
KEY `ind_buma`(`playdatetime`,`licenseid`,`playitemid`) USING BTREE) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=68644363 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Is there any way to define a better key or index to speed up the query

Kind regards,

Bjørn

Comment: Where you tried `EXPLAIN`ing the query (Although it look like it should use the KEY in this case, but I'm not sure)

Comment: I think (just a guess based on what you provided) an index only on `(playdatetime,licenseid)` would perform better.

Comment: @AlonEitan When i run the explain comment before it    

1 SIMPLE buma range ind_buma ind_buma 9  5564864 Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort

Comment: @Subblaze91 It's too broad (At least for me) to give you a suggestion. For me, this [article](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/) help a lot to make queries run faster on my website (But I don't have tables with milloins of rows thogh)

Answer (score 0):

Try to index only playdatetime, licenseid, playitemid alone or groupe only `licenseid`,`playitemid`.

MySQL 5.1 is very old (10 years old).
Upgrade to 5.7 for a good performance increase (or use a mysql fork like mariadb 10.1).

You can also try to calculate this : Date_sub(Curdate(), INTERVAL 1 month) without mysql (php strtotime or other), and use mysql cache for instant request if you call it more than one time per day, be carefull dont use more than 128MB, it can decrease performances too).